# ms-access: update record where some field = textbox value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

can someone please help me with the following query

i need to update a datasheet (table) in access through a form:

i will have something like this

```
SQLtext = "update table1 set column1="sometext" where column2=textbox1.value"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLtext
```

is this possible to do?

i have a textbox on a form and when i click a button on that form i want to update data in the datasheet where one of the columns is equal to the value property of a textbox

thank you!

Comment: Consider using CurrentDb.Execute with dbFailOnError instead of DoCmd.RunSQL.  For another approach, look at David Fenton's SQLRun function: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35365281/reusing-a-door-prize-no--part-two-of-the-questions.aspx

Comment: A datasheet and a table are not by any means the same thing. A datasheet is a user interface object that can represent be a table, a saved QueryDef or a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need (note the subtle change)

```
SQLtext = "update table1 set column1='sometext' where column2='" & textbox1.value & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLtext
```

Note: For production code you will want to escape out any single quotes in the textbox1.value string using the string replace function, otherwise you will get a SQL error whenever a user types a single quote in that field.